# Suspending AKKA actor

Tags: akka

Suppose there are messages in the mailbox. Is it possible to suspend the Actor from processing the messages and resume it at a later point without holding the thread.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Akka provides a way of changing the behavior of an actor using `context.become()` and `context.unbecome()`. It also provides a way to `stash()` and `unstash()` your message once you have changed your behavior.

The idea would be to `become()` a new behavior that basically does nothing (like suspended) but stash the messages. Once a certain condition is met, the actor `unbecome()`s and `unstashAll()` the messages to put them back again in the mailbox and start processing them again.

You can find a good example in the Akka docs (look for Stash): http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html

Comment: Thanks.. is this also applicable in java. My requirement is to stop the actor processing any messages (suspend). The request to suspend can come based on the unavailability of an external system.

Comment: Yes, this can be done in Java as well. Look for Stash here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html . In your use case, when the external system becomes unavailable, you can make your actor become a 'suspending' state where all new messages get stashed. Once the external system is available again, your actor unbecome and unstashes all messages.